# Serverless Stack Applications

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, serverless-framework

I have recently came across this term **"Serverless Stack"** and while I did a little research about it, I found it helps us in creating serverless web applications using framework like **ReactJS** and **DynamoDB** for backend which can be hosted over cloud using **AWS**.

However when it comes to the scalability of applications, there is very little to no information available across various blogs.

Had anyone tried this stack in your applications?.

I would want to hear,

1. What are the other tech stack (languages, frameworks) which can be used as part of this new **Serverless Stack**
2. Does it scale well? (Particularly when a website has more viewers)

Can someone shed some light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience I can tell you that what you are talking about is also known as **no-backend** applications ([resource](http://nobackend.org/)).

The principle of this approach is that you can abstract a number of features that traditionally are implemented into the server tier, and move them into decoupled services exposed as **SaaS**.

As you mentioned, a famous example are the smartphone hybrid applications that rely only onto [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) that provides them **authentication**, **authorization** and other few backend features.

If you need another kind of feature, like emails, you can do it within your frontend code by using a proper email service provider.

In terms of **scalability** what you have to do is simply to **scale the services** that you are using, for example using a bigger Firebase plan.

In terms of **security** you have to understand that in a web application your code is always visible so all your business logic could be red, analized and easly hacked. This is why the no-backend approach fits better the mobile application needs, since they are wrapped into proper containers designed in order to grant a better level of obscuration about what your application is doing.

Hope this could help you

Comment: Nice explanation Andrea!. Thanks!

Comment: Why *no-backend* ? AWS Lambda or GCP Cloud Function are more than perfectly able to handle the business logic out of the frontend. You must be mistaking 'serverless' and 'no-backend'.

And in this case, you don't have to scale anything. It just scales on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the existing frameworks:

- apex: lets you build, deploy, and manage AWS Lambda functions with ease
- chalice: Python Serverless Microframework for AWS
- claudia: makes it easy to deploy Node.js projects to AWS Lambda and API Gateway
- serverless.com: helps building apps on AWS Lambda

Search "serverless" on github to find more.

AWS-based services seem to scale well but have a look at the competition too:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/
- https://cloud.google.com/functions/